# Is it possible to force browser instance specific cookies in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, session-cookies

If IE9 is started with the -nomerge option, session cookies will be separate for each instance

Is there any way to force this behavior to occur from within IE itself?  For example, Silverlight telling the browser it is running a new instance?

Can the Browser Session ID be changed programatically
(Some type of "open new instance nomerge") ?

Would this cause separate session cookies to be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no mechanism to do this from within web content. (FWIW, HTML5 sessionStorage is partitioned per tab, even though session cookies are shared).