# is it possible for a Silverlight to read the browser process id

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, pid

I am still trying to think of a solution to [Browser Specific Cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6145442/is-it-possible-to-force-browser-instance-specific-cookies-in-ie)

One idea I want to explore is if I can use the browser process instance ID.

Is it possible to read this Silverlight 4?  If so, how?

Comment: It might be better if you asked a "How do I do X bearing in mind problem Y?" sort of question.  Describe in reasonable detail both X (what it is you are trying to achieve) and Y (the specific behaviour of browsers that is causing you a problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your specific question is: no you can't access the process instance ID.